# What does the notation $\textbf{x} \langle\textbf{Y} \rangle $ mean if $\textbf{Y} \subseteq \textbf{X}$ for random variables?

Tags: probability, notation

I was reading daphne's Probabilistic Graphical Models book and she introduces some notation about sets of random variables that I am confused about (on page 21 section 2.1.3.2).

Before I ask my question let me start with some notation introduced in the book. Let capital non-bold stand for random variables say $X$ is a r.v. Let little non bold stand for the assignment to a random variable say $(X = x)$. Also, let me define captial bold letters as sets of random variables. For example $\textbf{X}, \textbf{Y}, \textbf{Z}$ are three sets of random variables. Let small bold letters denote assigments to these sets $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}, \textbf{z}$ i.e. it denotes assigments of values to the variables in these sets. Let $Val(\textbf{X})$ be the values that the set of random variables can take.

Finally here is the statement in the book's definition I am having a hard time understanding:

> For $\textbf{Y} \subseteq \textbf{X}$, we use $\textbf{x} \langle\textbf{Y}  \rangle $ to refer to the assignment within $\textbf{x}$ to the variables in $\textbf{Y}.$

The specific part that confuses me is the word "within". Thats the part I do not understand specifically. I understand that the set of random variables $\textbf{Y}$ has some random variables in common  $\textbf{X}$ (or maybe equal), but I am not sure what within means.

Basically, I wish to understand what the notation $\textbf{x} \langle\textbf{Y}\rangle$ means.

As an extention to this notation (and question), the author then extends it by saying the following (which doesn't make sense to me yet since the first part didn't make sense):

> For two assigments $\textbf{x}$ (to $\textbf{X}$) and $\textbf{y}$ (to $\textbf{Y}$), we say that $\textbf{x} \sim \textbf{y}$ if they agree on the variables in their intersection, that is, $\textbf{x} \langle \textbf{X} \cap \textbf{Y} \rangle = \textbf{y}\langle \textbf{X} \cap \textbf{Y} \rangle$.

Comment: Can you explain what $\bf x$ means? I don't follow what "assignment" in general means here.

Comment: Yes. I was confused about that too, but this is what I take it means. Say we have $\textbf{X} = {X_1, X_2, X_3}$. There are some valid assignments to the r.v.s $X_1, X_2, X_3$ say, $(X_1 = 1), (X_2 = 1), (X_1 = 3)$. Then $\textbf{x} = <1,2,3>$

Comment: Let me put more information of what that notation means according to the auther of the book that invented it. Give me a second.

Comment: The funny things is that the book says: " We extend the definition of $Val( \textbf{X} )$ to refer to the sets of variables in the obvious way", which wasn't too obvious too me without thinking about it. hehe

Comment: I think I get it. If ${\bf X} = \{ X_1,X_2,X_3 \}$, ${\bf Y} = \{ X_1,X_2 \}$, ${\bf x} = \{ X_1=1,X_2=2,X_3=3 \}$, then ${\bf x}\langle {\bf Y} \rangle = \{ X_1=1,X_2=2 \}$. This is speculation but not much else seems to make sense.

Comment: Yep. I believe you have nailed it!

Comment: @Ian, I think that makes sense! Feel free to post your answer and with an example should make it clear! thnx :)